# if else statement that doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I have a statement that should move an image forward and back, but it seems to only move my animation forward.. once.

This is how I've been thinking:

```
var rect1;
var rect2;
var xEnd = 50;
var xEnd2 = 150;

function init() {
    paper = Raphael("loadSVG");
    rect1 = paper.rect(150, 20, 50, 50);
    rect1.attr({
        fill: "#ffaaaa",
        "stroke-width": 3
    });
};

function moveRect1() {
    if (rect1.animate({
        x: xEnd
    })) {
        rect1.animate({
            x: xEnd
        });
    }
    else {
        rect1.animate({
            x: xEnd2
        });
    }
};
```

So my problem is that it only moves my animation once to 50, but if I press the button again nothing happens.

Any idea?

Comment: Do not change your question after you've already received answers. It makes them obsolete and nonsensical.

Answer (score 2):

This will always be `true`...

```
if (rect1.animate({x: xEnd})) {
```

...because you're passing an object to the `if`, and objects are always true.

I assume you mean to pass some property of `rect1` to be evaluated instead.

[image]

```
  ^^------------------^^
```

Comment: Well, i got that park so i wrote the code in a different way. The animation works but act weird when i press the start button twice, since i want the the start button to restart the animation directly from the X value =/

Comment: @FelipeOtarola: So the first time it should go to `xEnd`, then the next time it goes to `xEnd2`, and then the next time it goes back to `xEnd`, and so on, back and forth?

Comment: Exactly, And it works, but when I press start twice it start act crazy weird. I will update my code to show you.

Comment: @down-voter: ***The question was changed long after I answered.***

Answer (score 1):

I think I see what the problem is. Each time you click your button, you are in effect setting off another animation cycle on top of the one that's already running. So say your square goes right, then left. If you click on the left cycle, a new animation applies on top going right.

I've tried to illustrate this point [here](http://jsfiddle.net/amadanNM/ypfyx/#base). click the small green square to start your first cycle. Each click will start a new cycle. Each cycle will attempt to change the color. When you click it more than once, you'll see that as well as the square juddering around, the color will change as each animation cycle comes to the fore.

Your click event on the button simply needs to stop the existing animation (rect1.halt()) before starting the next animation cycle.

Hope that helps.

N.